# leading coefficient of Hilbert polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, hilbert-polynomial

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ and $I$ be a homogeneous $J$-**primary** ideal, where $J=\sqrt{I}$ and $J$ is a homogeneous prime ideal. Assume $V(J)$ is a $d$-dim projective subvariety inside $\mathbb{P}^n$.

I have a few questions concerning the Hilbert polynomials of $I$ and $J$ which I will call them $h_I$ and $h_J$.

The degree of polynomial $h_I$ and $h_J$ should be $d$.

Let the leading coefficient of $h_I$ and $h_J$ be $\frac{a_I}{d!}$ and $\frac{a_J}{d!}$.

How to show that $a_J$ divides $a_I$ or is there any counterexample that this is not true?

Comment: I assume $h_I$ is the Hilbert polynomial of $R/I$, not of the $R$-module $I$?

Comment: @Jesko Hüttenhain, you are right.

Comment: Take $I = (x_0)^2$ and $J = (x_0)$.

Comment: @Youngsu,  degree($I$)=2, degree($J$)=1.

Comment: Oh right I should have meant a_J divides a_I. I edited my question.

Comment: I see. I believe that the associativity formula for Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity answers your question positively. I do not think $I$ being $J$-primary is necessary as this multiplicity is blind to embedded components. In other words, $\sqrt{I} = J$ would be enough.

Comment: @Youngsu , thank you. I will check that out.